# Java can an object be serialized if it uses non-serializable data in a method?

Tags: java, serialization, spigot

I have the following class:

```
public class Town implements Serializable {
    public String name = "Town";
    public String color = "White";
    public ArrayList<UUID> mayors = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<UUID> cabinet = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<UUID> citizens = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I want to add an "addPlayer" void, that adds the UUID of a player, (working on a spigot/minecraft plugin) obtained from Player.getUniqueID()  (returns a UUID object), I'm wondering if my method could look like this:

```
public void addPlayer (Player p){
    citizens.add(p.getUniqueID());
}
```

or if since the Player object is not serializable if I would need to just have the method take a UUID instead of a player?

Simply put, can non-serializable objects be used within the scope of functions since they aren't being used as field variables?

I know it'd be super easy to just put in a UUID instead of player object if necessary, but knowing whether or not I can do this will help me a lot with some other things I have planned for the project

Comment: Only the fields need to be serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Serialize is only concerned with the state of an object, which is determined by the instance varibles and not by its methods.

To use non-serializable objects within the Serializable class without affecting serializabilty of the class itself like in your case; your `Player` obj will only used within the scope of the `addPlayer` method. Its not stored as an instance variable on your `Town` class so it does not really affect the serializabilty of your `Town` class. So yes you can use your `addPlayer(Player p)` method as is. The only thing that gets serialized are the fields of your Town class such as `(name, color, mayors, cabinet, citizens)`. So no need to worry about your `Player` not being serializable.